# how to deploy a pretrained face detection pickle file on azure and use it as an endpoint

Tags: azure, machine-learning, deployment, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project using a Raspberry Pi, and I've successfully trained machine learning models locally. Now, I'm looking to deploy these models on Azure and make API calls to utilize them. However, I'm facing some challenges in deploying the models on Azure. I and new to azure and any guidance or steps you can provide to help me with this deployment process would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried looking online? There are multiple articles which addresses this question. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask-b95af8fe34d4   ; https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-as-a-rest-api-4a03b865c166   ; https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-python-codes-with-azure-functions-45a9b4485760

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a model in Azure ML and create REST API Endpoint, you can check this tutorial [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-with-rest?view=azureml-api-2) which demonstrate the basics of steps including:

- Upload and register code
- Upload and register model
- Create environment
- Create endpoint
- Create deployment

Also, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-custom-container?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python) which contains various examples about use of custom container to deploy a model to an online endpoint and this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/endpoints/online/managed/online-endpoints-simple-deployment.ipynb) that demonstrate the deployment of a simple pickle model.